# Pulling data from localstorage

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to retrieve data from local storage and then display this to the user.
What I want to happen is the user to be able to select a name from a drop down menu (this part works) and then display this data on screen (I can do this part).

The code to select a user is -

```
$scope.SelectedChanged = function() {

  $scope.showBox = $scope.userSelected;

};
```

And the code to then cycle through the array of users, and take the correct data is -

```
$scope.LoadUserData = function() {

  //console.log("Function run");

  for (var i = 0; i < $localStorage.users.length; i++) {
    //console.log("Function run");
    var userTmp = $localStorage.users[i];

    if (userTmp.name == $scope.userSelected) {
      //PROBLEM IS HERE. ISNT ACCESSING USERSELECTED
      console.log($scope.userSelected);

      user = {
        name: userTmp.name,
        email: userTmp.email,
        index: i
      };

      console.log(user);
    }
  }
};
```

When I test it, the Function run tests work correctly. So I think the issue is with the if statement, but i'm not sure as to why. Any advice?

Edit - Just to clarify, in local storage users are saved as objects names "users", with email and name being variables inside the object.

Comment: Have to tried to pass the **userSelected** to your **LoadUserData** function directly as like **LoadUserData(userSelected)**. If not, consider this way.

Comment: I just tried this. It will now show some users profiles in the console log, but says names are undefined. Also its pulling many profiles, even though only one choice is selected. Always pulling 15 profiles each time the function is run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like the below code as I suggested to do in the comment section above. Also check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q7RSuZqAfbk31wMY53mc?p=preview) link for the example scenario.

**Template:**

```
<select ng-model="selectedUser" ng-options="usr.name as usr.name for usr in userList" ng-change="LoadUserData(selectedUser);"></select>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.LoadUserData = function(selectedUser) {
    var index = $scope.userList.map(function (usr) { return usr.name; }).indexOf(selectedUser);
    $scope.activeUser = $scope.userList[index];
    console.log($scope.activeUser);
};
```